# How to dynamically load a Rust library in C?

Tags: c, gcc, rust, dynamic-linking, dlsym

I'm trying to dynamically link a Rust .so library with a C program in Linux with gcc. Using only `dlopen` and `dlclose` results in no errors, but I get a segmentation fault with the following code:

```
char * (*my_function)(char *);
char *my_input_string = "foo";

//...abbreviated code...

my_function = dlsym(handle, "my_function");
char *my_output_string = (*my_function)(my_input_string);
```

I'm using `gcc -g foo.c -ldl -o foo` to compile, if that matters.

I know that it's finding the symbol because I used `#[no_mangle]` in the rust library and the `my_function` pointer is not null

Comment: What are the Rust signature for `my_function`?

Comment: @malbarbo It's `pub extern "C" fn my_function(my_string: *const c_char) -> *const c_char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran it through `gdb` and it turns out the library was trying to call a function in the calling program that didn't exist.